# What determines component visibility in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, components, visibility

I'm writing a Java GUI program that uses a JFrame object and several JPanel objects. The JPanel objects use the paint() and repaint() methods, and some of the JPanel ojbects have JLabels and JButtons. When I run the program some of these various components are not visible in the way I want them to be i.e. it seems though some are hiding others.

What determines which components are visible when the program is run? Does it depend on the order in which the components are added to the top-level container, or the order in which each object's paint() method is called? Can this default visibility be overridden?

Edit: I should add that some JPanels (and their components) overlap each other.

Edit:
Here is an example program. What determines which components are visible on screen? For example, why is Button1 visible when Button2 is not?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test1 extends JFrame {

  public Test1() {
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(500, 700);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    add(new Test2());
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        new Test1();
      }
    });
  }
}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test2 extends JPanel {

  public Test2() {
    setBounds(0, 0, 300, 500);
    setLayout(null);
    add(new Test3());
    add(new Test4());
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 250, 450);
  }
}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test3 extends JPanel {

  public Test3() {
    setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.fillRect(40, 50, 200, 150);
  }
}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test4 extends JPanel {

  public JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label1");
  public JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label2");

  public JButton button1 = new JButton("Button1");
  public JButton button2 = new JButton("Button2");

  public Test4() {
    setBounds(0, 300, 300, 200);

    add(label1);
    add(label2);
    add(button1);
    add(button2);

    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Each of them should inherit a `setVisible(boolean newVisibility)` method. Are you calling it properly?

Comment: visible to the user, or your method?

Comment: I don't think he's questioning the `setVisible()` method to determine whether the component is being rendered, but rather the order in which the components are rendered.

Comment: I mean visibility to the user. If components/graphics overlap, which ones are visible on the screen i.e which ones hide the others?

Comment: Component visibility functions just as you'd expect it to: If a component is covered by an opaque component, then the covered portion of the ones below are not seen. I have a feeling that there is a hidden underlying problem that is the genesis of this question, and that you're not likely going to solve whatever specific problem you have unless you spell it out for us in detail and with pertinent code, including your [mcve]. Who knows, the solution may be as simple as using a CardLayout, but let's avoid making wild guesses -- please tell and show us the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I should add that some JPanels (and their components) overlap each other.

The ZOrder controls the order in which components are painted. A component with a higher ZOrder is painted first.

> Does it depend on the order in which the components are added to the top-level container

Yes, the ZOrder is assigned as a Component is added to the Container, so the last component added will be painted first.

You can use the `setComponentZOrder(...)` method of the `Container` class to manually change the ZOrder (and thus the order of painting). For example if you drag a component and want it painted on top, you would set its ZOrder to 0.

You may want to check out the [Overlap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/). It allows you to control how the components are displayed wen they overlap (although is does make all components the same size)

> Here is an example program.

You should never write an application like that as you will get all kinds of problems:

1. Don't use the null layout managers.
2. Don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent() and making sure you invoke super.paintComponent(...).
3. Don't stack panels on top of one another. A JPanel is opaque, so adding components on top of one another will hide the component below.

> why is Button1 visible when Button2 is not?

Button1 is painted because it has focus. If you move your mouse beside button2 it will also be painted because it responds to the mouseOver event.

If you resize the frame, both button will disappear because the panels will be repainted based on ZOrder.

I really have no idea what you are trying to do with that code. All I can say is don't do it. Use layout managers.

Comment: Thanks camickr - that's really helpful. I guess I wrote the program not fully understanding how to use layout managers, ZOrder and painting. I've got a better focus now on what I need to learn.